# Find maximum similar value pairs from two lists

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I got this question in an interview.

Values can only be : M, A, S.

```
List 1:
Index  : 1  2  3  4  5  6
Values : M  A  S  A  M  A

List 2:
Index  : 7  8  9  10 11 12
Values : S  A  M  A  S  A
```

In these lists I needed to find the maximum pairs of same values in same order.

```
Output : 
Solution 1 : 4 pairs 
             (Indexes from List1:List2) : 
             (3:7) 
             (4:8)
             (5:9)
             (6:10) or (6:12)

Solution 2 : 4 pairs
             (Indexes from List1:List2) : 
             (1:9) 
             (2:10)
             (3:11)
             (4:12) or (6:12)
```

I can't find a way of achieving it even after giving lot of thought. Can anybody provide the algo for this?

Comment: Proper ordering should be maintained. One value can appear only in 1 pair.

Comment: Isn't that the longest common substring, where your solutions are MASA and SAMA (and the alternatoves for the fourth pair are given to obscure the fact)?

Comment: @MOehm it will be longest common subsequence instead of substring because the letters needn't be adjacent I believe.

Comment: @SomeDude: Yes, that makes sense and also explains why there are two options for the last pair.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is another way of asking the [Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) between two strings. Get the longest common subsequence between those strings and from the bottom up table get the indices from both the strings. The subsequence part maintains the property that ordering should be maintained.